# JSF Primefaces Datatable and Field keeping the previous values

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, master-detail

Im new to JSF/Primefaces. I already have searched for answers several weeks and could not find nothing.

Im developing an Inventory System (customized for an IT Department).

I have several views with the same/related problem, I think:

**Issue # 1:** When I submit a new value via a form with **one inpuText** and **one selectOneMenu** and the datatable get refreshed, the new value is added the first time, but when I select another item en submit the values again it adds the previous value of **the selectOneMenu.** **Note:** Only in the DataTable, since in the data base the correct record is saved.

I have tried changing the **ViewScoped** to **RequestScope**, it appears to be solved, but now, when I try to edit a row it adds it as a new value instead. so that the Datatable shows the row I tried to edit and the edited as a new one.

See the image:

[Subcategory View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGGz9.jpg)

**JSF Page: Subcategory View**

```html
<h:form id="subcategory">
                    <p:growl id="message" autoUpdate="true" showDetail="true"/>
          <p:fieldset id="subcategoryFS" legend="New Sub-Category" toggleable="true" collapsed="true">

                        <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="2">

                            <p:selectOneMenu id="cboCategory"
                                             value="#{subcategoryController.category.categoryId}"
                                             style="width: 100%">

                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Category" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true"/>
                                <f:selectItems value="#{subcategoryController.categoryList}"
                                               var="subcat"
                                               itemLabel="#{subcat.categoryName}"
                                               itemValue="#{subcat.categoryId}"/>
                                <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{subcategoryController.categoryChange()}"/>
                            </p:selectOneMenu>

                            <p:inputText id="Sub_Category_Name"
                                         value="#{subcategoryController.subcategory.subcategoryName}"
                                         required="true"
                                         style="width: 250px;"/>

                            <p:commandButton id="newSubCatCombtn"
                                             value="Add"
                                             icon="ui-icon-plus"
                                             actionListener="#{subcategoryController.save()}"
                                             style="width: 100%"
                                             update="subcategory, :subCatDTForm:subCatDT"/>

                        </h:panelGrid>
                        <p:watermark for="Sub_Category_Name" value="Sub-Category Name" id="Sub_Category_NameWM"/>

                    </p:fieldset>
                </h:form>
                <h:form id="subCatDTForm">

                    <p:contextMenu for="subCatDT">
                        <p:menuitem value="Edit" icon="ui-icon-pencil"
                                    oncomplete="PF('subCatDialog').show()"
                                    update=":subCatDialogT"/>
                        <p:menuitem value="Delete"
                                    icon="ui-icon-close"
                                    actionListener="#{subcategoryController.remove()}"
                                    update="subCatDT"/>
                    </p:contextMenu>

                    <p:dataTable id="subCatDT" var="subcatDataTable" value="#{subcategoryController.subcategoryList}"
                                 rowKey="#{subcatDataTable.subcategoryId}"
                                 selectionMode="single"
                                 selection="#{subcategoryController.selectedSubcategory}"
                                 emptyMessage="No subcategories recorded yet">

                        <p:column headerText="ID">
                            <h:outputText value="#{subcatDataTable.subcategoryId}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Sub-Category">
                            <h:outputText value="#{subcatDataTable.subcategoryName}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Category">
                            <h:outputText value="#{subcatDataTable.categoryId.categoryName}"/>
                        </p:column>

                    </p:dataTable>
                </h:form>
```

**Category Bean:**

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class CategoryController implements Serializable {

    @EJB
    CategoryFacadeLocal categoryEJB;
    @Inject
    private Category category;
    @Inject
    private Category selectedCategory;

    private List<Category> categoryList;
    private List<Category> tempcategoryList;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        categoryList = categoryEJB.findAll();
    }

    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public List<Category> getCategoryList() {
        return categoryList;
    }

    public void setCategoryList(List<Category> categoryList) {
        this.categoryList = categoryList;
    }

    public Category getSelectedCategory() {
        return selectedCategory;
    }

    public void setSelectedCategory(Category selectedCategory) {
        this.selectedCategory = selectedCategory;
    }

    public void save() {//Guarda la categoria 

        try {

            tempcategoryList = categoryEJB.findCategoryByName(category); // Carga la lista si esta category ya existe en la base de datos.

            if (tempcategoryList.isEmpty()) { // Si la lista esta vacia, guarda la nueva categoria.

                categoryEJB.create(category); // Guarda esta categoria en la base de datos.
                init(); // Recarga la lista con la base de datos despues de agregar la nueva categoria.

                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(
                        FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Info", "Category: " + category.getCategoryName() + " created"));

                category.setCategoryName(""); // limpia los CategoryName en la vista.
                category.setCategoryDetail(""); // limpia los CategoryDetail en la vista.

            } else {

                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(
                        FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "Info", "Category: " + category.getCategoryName() + " created"));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(
                    FacesMessage.SEVERITY_FATAL, "Info", "Category: " + category.getCategoryName() + " not created"));
        }
    }
```

**Issue # 2:** Something related is happening when I try to edit a row with a dialog. The selectOneMenu's are not loading the values of the selected row:

See the image:

[Dialog to edit the values of a saved category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwtOt.jpg)

**SubCategory Bean:**

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class SubcategoryController implements Serializable {

    @EJB
    private SubcategoryFacadeLocal EJBsubcategory;
    @EJB
    private CategoryFacadeLocal EJBcategory;
    @Inject
    private Subcategory subcategory;
    @Inject
    private Category category;
    @Inject
    private Subcategory selectedSubcategory;
    @Inject
    private Category selectedCategory;

    private List<Category> categoryList;
    private List<Subcategory> subcategoryList;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        categoryList = EJBcategory.findAll();
        subcategoryList = EJBsubcategory.findAll();
    }

    public Subcategory getSubcategory() {
        return subcategory;
    }

    public void setSubcategory(Subcategory subcategory) {
        this.subcategory = subcategory;
    }

    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public List<Category> getCategoryList() {
        return categoryList;
    }

    public void setCategoryList(List<Category> categoryList) {
        this.categoryList = categoryList;
    }

    public List<Subcategory> getSubcategoryList() {
        return subcategoryList;
    }

    public void setSubcategoryList(List<Subcategory> subcategoryList) {
        this.subcategoryList = subcategoryList;
    }

    public Subcategory getSelectedSubcategory() {
        return selectedSubcategory;
    }

    public void setSelectedSubcategory(Subcategory selectedSubcategory) {
        this.selectedSubcategory = selectedSubcategory;
    }

    public Category getSelectedCategory() {
        return selectedCategory;
    }

    public void setSelectedCategory(Category selectedCategory) {
        this.selectedCategory = selectedCategory;
    }

    public void save() {

        try {

            subcategory.setCategoryId(category);

            EJBsubcategory.create(subcategory);
            this.init();

            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(
                    FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Info", "Subcategory: " + subcategory.getSubcategoryName() + " saved"));

            subcategory.setSubcategoryName("");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(
                    FacesMessage.SEVERITY_FATAL, "Warning", "Subcategory: " + subcategory.getSubcategoryName() + " not saved"));
        }
    }

    public void edit() {

        try {

            selectedSubcategory.setCategoryId(selectedCategory);

            EJBsubcategory.edit(selectedSubcategory);
            this.init();

            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(
                    FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Info", "Subcategory: " + selectedSubcategory.getSubcategoryName() + " updated"));

            selectedSubcategory.setSubcategoryName("");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(
                    FacesMessage.SEVERITY_FATAL, "Warning", "Subcategory: " + selectedSubcategory.getSubcategoryName() + " not updated"));
        }
    }

    public void remove() {

        try {

            EJBsubcategory.remove(selectedSubcategory);
            this.init();

            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(
                    FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Info", "Subcategory: " + selectedSubcategory.getSubcategoryName() + " deleted"));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(
                    FacesMessage.SEVERITY_FATAL, "Warning", "Subcategory: " + selectedSubcategory.getSubcategoryName() + " not deleted"));
        }
    }
```

These issues are happeing in every View of the web app.
I would appreciate if you guys could help me. What am I doing wrong? Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide the code of your subCatDialog ?

Comment: Also, can you provide your bean full code ? if not, at least the method you're calling in your listeners.

Comment: This is the wrong master-detail approach. `@Inject` is supposed to inject backing beans or service facades, not model entities. Whilst the abovelinked duplicate uses a `<p:dialog>` for adding items, exactly the same approach is applicable on your `<p:fieldset>`.

Comment: @BalusC What the correct approach would be? instead of inject I should create a new instance using New 'Entity' ()? Thanks for your help

Comment: See the abovelinked duplicate for the kickoff example.

Comment: @BalusC Many thanks. It worked like a charm! Thanks a lot. Your comments were a big help.